# How do I regain my Ubuntu Linux login capability as well as gain full Internet interconnectivity?

Tags: ubuntu, login, network-interface, ethernet

On Ubuntu 16.04, after I configured our Ethernet interface using Network IPV4 settings for IP address, gateway and DNS IP addresses, I could not ping www.msn.com or 192.168.10.xx. I tested our Ethernet interface with ifconfig and it appeared to be transmitting packets.

At this point in time , the Ubuntu 16.04 was connected  to a Netgear Ethernet switch.

Then, I disconnected the Ubuntu 16.04 from the Netgear Ethernet switch and connected its Comcast Internet port directly into a wall mounted Ethernet port known to be functional. The reason I did this was to try to fix the ping problem. Instead, I lost the ability to login with my Ubuntu 16.04 password. However , when I "loginned' as guest, I had full Internet and ping connectivity.

After I disconnected the Ubuntu 16.04 Lenevo desktop from the Netgear switch, I  rebooted the desktop computer. Could I have lost the pre-existing keyboard mappings at this time?

How do I regain my login capability as well as gain full Internet interconnectivity?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Go in single-user mode, change password - and check if anything else is OK - and then you can log.

Comment: @FarazX, Thank you for your very nice comment. How do I go into single-user mode on the Ubuntu Lenovo Thinkstation desktop?

Comment: I'm not a fan of Ubuntu, but I think you should reboot, and quickly hold the `Shift` key which will bring up the GNU GRUB menu. (you shouldn't see Ubuntu logo). Then select the line which starts with "Advanced options" or ending with (recovery mode) or something similar. Press Return and your machine will begin the boot process.

Comment: Here you are: [UbuntuRecoveryMode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)

Comment: @FarazX, Thank you for your assitance. In single-user mode , what command line do I type to change the password?

Comment: `passwd theUserYouWant` for instance `passwd Frank`

Comment: See also [How to reset your password in Ubuntu](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword)